# Two boost::accumulators::accumulator_set interfere with each other

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-accumulators

I have created a class `Histogram` in [my code](https://github.com/martin-ueding/physik590/tree/d3081a1ef7d03f7a5d732e4b16dbd28e190217b8/Programm) which is intended as a wrapper for `boost::accumulators::accumulator_set` from Boost 1.54. The things that seem important to my problem are those lines from the [`Histogram.hpp`](https://github.com/martin-ueding/physik590/blob/d3081a1ef7d03f7a5d732e4b16dbd28e190217b8/Programm/Histogram.hpp) file:

```
using namespace boost::accumulators;

class Histogram {
    public:
        Histogram(int bins, size_t cache);
        accumulator_set<double,
                        features<tag::min, tag::max, tag::mean, tag::density>> acc;
};
```

Then in [`Histogram.cpp`](https://github.com/martin-ueding/physik590/blob/d3081a1ef7d03f7a5d732e4b16dbd28e190217b8/Programm/Histogram.cpp) I have the constructor:

```
Histogram::Histogram(int bins, size_t cache)
    : acc(accumulator_set<double,
          features<tag::min, tag::max, tag::mean, tag::density>>(
              tag::density::num_bins = bins,
              tag::density::cache_size = std::min(cache, MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES))) {
}
```

The code that uses this histogram (`do_iterations()` in [`main-metropolis.cpp`](https://github.com/martin-ueding/physik590/blob/d3081a1ef7d03f7a5d732e4b16dbd28e190217b8/Programm/main-metropolis.cpp)) starts with the following:

```
Histogram position_histogram{settings.position_hist_bins, settings.time_sites * settings.iterations};
//Histogram action_histogram{settings.action_hist_bins, settings.iterations};
```

It works just like I expect when I run it with the second line deactivated. My simulation generates some data points, puts it into the `Histogram::acc` and lets me extract it afterwards:

```
-2.86958    0
-2.37393    0.0002
-1.87829    0.0071
-1.38265    0.06621
-0.887001   0.23902
-0.391356   0.33247
0.104288    0.2342
0.599932    0.08449
1.09558 0.02843
1.59122 0.00775
2.08687 0.00012
2.58251 1e-05
# Min -2.37393
# Max 2.58251
# Mean -0.0809983
```

Then I activate the line, and the `position_histogram` works in a really strange way. The bins are all zero, but the data is distributed into the overflow bins in the first and last bin:

```
0   0.57785
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0.42215
# Min -2.37393
# Max 2.58251
# Mean -0.0809983
```

If I swap the lines, it is `action_histogram` that breaks. So the second one always breaks the first one. Why does an initialization of a second `Histogram` and therefore a second `accumulator_set` causes the first one to break?

---

Please use revision `d3081a1ef7` when you browse through [the code](https://github.com/martin-ueding/physik590/tree/d3081a1ef7d03f7a5d732e4b16dbd28e190217b8/Programm) since I build my own histogram implementation by now to continue work.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to debug this or supply more information.

I have used accumulators and always with more than one instance simultaneously in my research proof-of-concepts, and I have not encountered this. Then I realized I never did a `density` histogram in parallel, so I tested it out.

It pans out in my test based on your declarations, see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75438020b6f25a11)**:

```
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace boost::accumulators;

static const size_t MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES = 32;

class Histogram {
    public:
        Histogram(int bins, size_t cache)
            : acc(accumulator_set<double,
                    features<tag::min, tag::max, tag::mean, tag::density>>(
                        tag::density::num_bins = bins,
                        tag::density::cache_size = std::min(cache, MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES))) {
            }        

        accumulator_set<double,
                        features<tag::min, tag::max, tag::mean, tag::density>> acc;
};

int main()
{
    Histogram position_histogram { 10, 32 };
    Histogram action_histogram   { 10, 32 };

    auto random = boost::bind(boost::uniform_real<double>(-100,100), boost::mt19937(42));

    size_t samples = 1<<20;
    while (samples--)
    {
        auto v = random();
        position_histogram.acc(v);
        action_histogram.acc(v);
    }

    for (auto& acc : { position_histogram.acc, action_histogram.acc })
    {
        auto hist = density(acc);

        double total = 0.0;

        for( int i = 0; i < hist.size(); i++ ) 
        {
            std::cout << "Bin lower bound: " << hist[i].first << ", Value: " << hist[i].second << std::endl; 
            total += hist[i].second;
        }

        std::cout << "Total: " << total << std::endl; //should be 1 (and it is)
    }
}
```

Output, as expected:

```
Bin lower bound: -119.673, Value: 0.000766754
Bin lower bound: -99.8442, Value: 0.099205
Bin lower bound: -80.0156, Value: 0.0987797
Bin lower bound: -60.1869, Value: 0.0990477
Bin lower bound: -40.3583, Value: 0.0991993
Bin lower bound: -20.5296, Value: 0.0989904
Bin lower bound: -0.700967, Value: 0.0993652
Bin lower bound: 19.1277, Value: 0.0993567
Bin lower bound: 38.9563, Value: 0.0993252
Bin lower bound: 58.785, Value: 0.0993109
Bin lower bound: 78.6137, Value: 0.0989342
Bin lower bound: 98.4423, Value: 0.00771904
Total: 1
Bin lower bound: -119.673, Value: 0.000766754
Bin lower bound: -99.8442, Value: 0.099205
Bin lower bound: -80.0156, Value: 0.0987797
Bin lower bound: -60.1869, Value: 0.0990477
Bin lower bound: -40.3583, Value: 0.0991993
Bin lower bound: -20.5296, Value: 0.0989904
Bin lower bound: -0.700967, Value: 0.0993652
Bin lower bound: 19.1277, Value: 0.0993567
Bin lower bound: 38.9563, Value: 0.0993252
Bin lower bound: 58.785, Value: 0.0993109
Bin lower bound: 78.6137, Value: 0.0989342
Bin lower bound: 98.4423, Value: 0.00771904
Total: 1
```

Also, when feeding both accumulators different samples, I couldn't make it display any obvious malfunctions.

Hope this helps you realize what is different about your situation (e.g. do you actually feed both accumulators the right samples?)

I've test with boost 1.53-1.55

Comment: I added links to the source code in the question. The accumulators should get the right samples, since one of them works and shows a reasonable histogram. What does the `template <typename Tag=int>` do?

Comment: Sorry about that tag. That was a left-over of an idea I had to diagnose potential problems. That turned out to be unnecessary. Ignore the tag :)

Comment: Does this feature have a name? I'd like to read about it as I am learning C++ right now. — So the problem in my code seems to created somewhere in the other complexity?

Comment: Tags are just template parameters. There's an idiom that can be used to generate unique, identical types by passing _empty_ struct types (tag types) to the template: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ab915cc933666bb - There's an unrelated archaic thing in the [C language](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=412). IOW, nothing related to your issue

Comment: Yes, the problem in your code seem to be created somewhere in (the) other complexity :(